# Merge Sort Error : Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, array-algorithms

I'm getting an error `Segmentation Fault:11`, please help.
variable info:(s:start, e:end, m:mid, n:array), testing for a sample array `n[] = {4,3,2,1}`. `a1` and `a2` are temporary arrays. I am guessing there's something with the calculation of `m:mid` and passing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int s, int e, int m, int n[]) {
    int l1 = m - s;
    int l2 = e - m + 1;
    int a1[l1];
    int a2[l2];
    for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        a1[i] = n[s + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < l2; j++) {
        a2[j] = n[s + m + j];
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    for (int k = 0; k < l1 + l2; k++) {
        if (a1[i] <= a2[j] && i != l1 && j != l2) {
            n[k] = a1[i];
            i++;
        } else if (a2[j] <= a1[i] && i != l1 && j != l2) {
            n[k] = a2[j];
            j++;
        } else if (j == l2 && i != l1) {
            n[k] = a1[i];
            i++;
        } else if(i == l1 && j != l2) {
            n[k] = a2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(int s, int e, int n[]) {
    if (s < e) {
        int m = (e - s) / 2;
        mergeSort(s, m - 1, n);
        mergeSort(m, e, n);
        merge(s, e, m, n);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n[] = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    int r = 4;
    mergeSort(0, r - 1, n);

    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", n[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Learning to use a debugger is possibly the most important skill of a programmer. It comes especially useful in such programs.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computation of `m` for the middle element is bogus: you get the offset of `m` from `s`, not its index into the array.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void mergeSort(int s, int e, int n[]) {
    if (s < e) {
        int m = s + (e - s + 1) / 2;
        mergeSort(s, m - 1, n);
        mergeSort(m, e, n);
        merge(s, e, m, n);
    }
}
```

There are other issues in your code, notably:

- you should check the offsets `i` and `j` **before**`dereferencing`a1[i]`and`a2[j]`.
- the offset `k` should not be used directly in the merge phase, you should store to `n[s + k]`.
- in the initialization loop for `a2`, you should use `a2[j] = n[m + j];` instead of `a2[j] = n[s + m + j];`

Note also that it is idiomatic to pass ranges in C with the first index included and the last index excluded. This allows for passing empty ranges, which your current method does not. It also makes the code much simpler and easier to read.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int s, int e, int m, int n[]) {
    int l1 = m - s;
    int l2 = e - m;
    int a1[l1];
    int a2[l2];

    for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        a1[i] = n[s + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < l2; j++) {
        a2[j] = n[m + j];
    }
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; k < l1 + l2; k++) {
        if (i < l1 && (j >= l2 || a1[i] <= a2[j])) {
            n[s + k] = a1[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            n[s + k] = a2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(int s, int e, int n[]) {
    if (e > s + 1) {
        int m = s + (e - s) / 2;
        mergeSort(s, m, n);
        mergeSort(m, e, n);
        merge(s, e, m, n);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n[] = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    int r = sizeof(n) / sizeof(n[0]);
    mergeSort(0, r, n);

    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", n[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code in several places. Try to use your debugger or pen & paper to understand what's going on under the hood.

```
void merge(int s, int e, int m, int n[]){

    int l1 = m-s + 1;
    int l2 = e - m;
    int a1[l1];
    int a2[l2];
    for(int i = 0; i < l1; i++){
        a1[i] = n[s+i];
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < l2; j++){
        a2[j] = n[m+j + 1];

    }


    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    for(int k = 0; k < l1+l2; k++){
        if(a1[i] <= a2[j] && i != l1 && j != l2){
            n[k] = a1[i];
            i++;
        }else if(a2[j] <= a1[i] && i != l1 && j != l2){
            n[k] = a2[j];
            j++;
        }else if(j == l2 && i != l1){
            n[k] = a1[i];
            i++;
        }else if(i == l1 && j != l2){
            n[k] = a2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

}
void mergeSort(int s, int e, int n[]){
        if(s<e){
            int m = s + (e-s)/2;
            mergeSort(s, m, n);
            mergeSort(m + 1, e, n);
            merge(s,e,m, n);
}
```

You will be fine I guess.

Comment: No, still the same problem.

Comment: @HarrySandhu Please check again

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Infinite_recursion) problem because of infinite recursive calls. Look

```
void mergeSort(int s, int e, int n[]){
    if(s<e){
        int m = (e-s)/2;
        mergeSort(s, m-1, n);
        mergeSort(m, e, n);
        merge(s,e,m, n);
    }

}
```

You pass these values of `s` and `e`:

```
s e function
-------------
0 3 mergeSort
    0 0 mergeSort -> end
    1 3 mergeSort
        0 0 mergeSort -> end
        1 3 mergeSort
            ... (infinite calls)
```

Then the stack grows and grows while new functions called until in the end it exceeds the maximum possible size, which leads to SEGFAULT.